# Python - Extract strings from a log file and write them into another file

Tags: python, file

I've got a log file like below:

```
sw2 switch_has sw2_p3.
sw1 transmits sw2_p2
/* BUG: axiom too complex: SubClassOf(ObjectOneOf([NamedIndividual(#t_air_sens2)]),DataHasValue(DataProperty(#qos_type),^^(latency,http://www.xcx.org/1900/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#PlainLiteral))) */
/* BUG: axiom too complex: SubClassOf(ObjectOneOf([NamedIndividual(#t_air_sens2)]),DataHasValue(DataProperty(#topic_type),^^(periodic,http://www.xcx.org/1901/11/22-rdf-syntax-ns#PlainLiteral))) */
...
```

what I'm interested in, is to extract specific words from `/* BUG...` lines and write them into separate file, something like below:

```
t_air_sens2 qos_type latency
t_air_sens2 topic_type periodic
...
```

I can do this with the help of `awk` and regex in shell like below:

```
awk -F'#|\\^\\^\\(' '{for (i=2; i<NF; i++) printf "%s%s", gensub(/[^[:alnum:]_].*/,"",1,$i), (i<(NF-1) ? OFS : ORS) }' output.txt > ./LogErrors/Properties.txt
```

How can I extract them using Python? (shall I use regex again, or..?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can of course use regex. I would read line by line, grab the lines the start with `'/* BUG:'`, then parse those as needed.

```
import re

target = r'/* BUG:'
bugs = []
with open('logfile.txt', 'r') as infile, open('output.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    # loop through logfile
    for line in infile:
        if line.startswith(target):
            # add line to bug list and strip newlines
            bugs.append(line.strip())
            # or just do regex parsing here
            # create match pattern groups with parentheses, escape literal parentheses with '\'
            match = re.search(r'NamedIndividual\(([\w#]+)\)]\),DataHasValue\(DataProperty\(([\w#]+)\),\^\^\(([\w#]+),', line)
            # if matches are found
            if match:
                # loop through match groups, write to output
                for group in match.groups():
                    outfile.write('{} '.format(group))
                outfile.write('\n')
```

Python has a pretty powerful regex module built-in: [re module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)

You can [search for a given pattern, then print out the matched groups as needed](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#match-objects).

Note: [raw strings](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals) (`r'xxxx'`) let you use unescaped characters.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried with following way and get the specific lines of the log file.

```
target =["BUGS"] # array with specific words

with open('demo.log', 'r') as infile, open('output.txt', 'w') as outfile:

    for line in infile:

        for phrase in target:

            if phrase in line:

                outfile.write('{} '.format(line))
```

This will output lines that include the words in the target and output is written in the output.txt file.